# Viewing user defined DOM propeties in native dev tools

Tags: dom, google-chrome-devtools, firefox-developer-tools

In Firebug you may open the DOM panel and view "user defined DOM propeties"

I am wondering if there is a way to view these properties in the native dev tools for firefox and/or chrome.

I can view them for all elements in body but cannot find a way to see those in the top level (equivalent of "window" in firebug)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And they're not really DOM properties. They're just object properties, where the objects happen to be DOM nodes.

`inspect($0)` in the console after you selected an element, or via the context menu:

[image]

so `inspect(window)` for things that are not in the inspector

Comment: Thanks, inspect(window) was what I was looking for.